# Advice for making 3D model (globe) of Earth using naturalearthdata

Tags: 3d-model, natural-earth, globe

New to GIS. I'd like to make a 3D globe using naturalearthdata that includes country borders.

Unfortunately, most tutorials I can find are for making "flat" maps. And when I include more search terms, I get tutorials that are "3d" in that they show terrain heights, but still not a globe.

Even if you can just tell me what I want to do is possible using such and such software (so I know I am not wasting time learning them).

I've got the data. I've got QGIS. I've got blender.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question to state the scale and extent of your 3D model.  At the size of a bowling ball, a 3D Earth would have borders tens if not hundreds of miles wide, eliminating many countries.  While it might be possible, I have to wonder if it's sensible.

Comment: See https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-terrain/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the data on a globe, you can use Google Earth.

Use QGIS to convert your data to kml:

- Right click on the layer in the TOC in QGIS:
  [image]
- Select Export > Save Features As
- Select KML as the format:
  [image]

Or use something like  [Cesium](https://cesium.com)